# How to prevent FastReport from opening datasets when they are purposely closed?

Tags: delphi, dataset, fastreport

I'm using a module that contains some `TfrxDBDataset` connected to `TFDQuery` to build a report. In the construction of the report there are parameters that must keep the queries closed. But, `TfrxDBDataset` objects are opening queries even with properties like `Enabled = false`, `OpenDataSource = False`. Apparently these are old backward compatibility properties
A workarround is not assigning the `dataset` property to `TfrxDBDataset`, but it is not very elegant. Does anyone know if there is a option in FastReport that prevents this behavior?

Comment: From the [OLH](https://www.fast-report.com/documentation/UserMan/index.html?tfrxdbdataset_component.htm) " Connect [the TfrxDBDataSet] to the data source by setting the “DataSet” property (for direct connection to a table or a query) or the “DataSource” property (for connection via a “TDataSource” component). The two methods are equivalent and mutually exclusive, though the first does allow data management without requiring a “TDataSource” component. To make the Delphi component (and the data connected to it) available to the report, any dataset used in the report must be enabled.  [...]"

Comment: @MartynA, Thanks, but, I had already read the help and also their forum to find a solution. I know that 'OpenDataSource' and 'CloseDataSource' are for backwards compatibility, but, 'Enabled' I don't know how it works effectively.